# sunspot - solr - How to do Exact match

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot

```
articles = Article.search do |s|
    s.fulltext "Java Script"
end
```

How do i tell sunspot like give me all the results which exactly matches "Java Script"
Right now am getting results like "Java, Unix Scripting"
(I think its the edge n gram which i am using for stemming takes this scripting results)

I found a couple of questions in stack overflow . unfortunately, no body answered the way i want. Hence i am posting this question here. I request the moderators not to mark it as duplicate

Answer (score 5):

Here is what you can add to your controller to make "Quoted Values" return an exact match.

```
  @search = Program.search do
     fulltext params[:search].gsub( '"', '"\\' ) unless params[:search].blank? 
     //...
  end
```

If you had text like this that is being searched...

```
the fox jumped over the tree
```

- Search for **fox over**  would return 1 row.
- However a search for **"fox over"** (in quotes) would return 0 rows.
- Search for **"fox jumped"** (also in quotes) would return 1 rows. This is the exact match.

Comment: Thanks for your HACK!!  But will you please tell me on thing, in  rails console in does't work properly. Correct me if  I'm doing any mistake